# JS Physics Acceleration Decay

Tags: javascript, physics

I am creating a physics engine which currently uses mouse acceleration (over time) to move boxes across the screen. I am aiming to have this mouse acceleration applied to the boxes decay over time by a factor of .8, however my current equation does not make the mouse acceleration converge to zero.

Box acceleration/velocity decay equations:

_this.vx is what I wish to have decay by 0.8, yet it compounds (in image).

[Log of velocity values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuweI.png)

```
 _this.update = function (t) {


        _this.x += _this.vx * 0.8 * t;
        _this.vx += (_this.ax *0.8) * t;



        console.log("Velocity: " + _this.vx);


    _this.y += _this.vy * t;
    _this.vy += (_this.ay + 440) * t;
```

Mouse acceleration capture:

```
    var mouse = {

    update: function (t)
    {  
        mouse.ox = mouse.x;
        mouse.oy = mouse.y;

    },
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    ox: 0,
    oy: 0,
    vx: 0,
    vy: 0,
    click: false
}

var now, after,timediff;

window.onmousemove = function (e)
{
    mouse.ox = mouse.x;
    mouse.oy = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.x;
    mouse.y = e.y;

    now = performance.now();
    timediff = now - after;
    mouse.vx = ((mouse.x - mouse.ox) / timediff)*100;
    mouse.vy = ((mouse.y - mouse.oy) / timediff)*100;
    after = now; 

    timediff = 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `t` at `_this.update`?

Comment: My apologies, it is a variable containing time from a clock function, it is used in update to measure time in seconds. Such as px/s

Comment: `t` would only increase,  yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 _this.vx += (_this.ax *0.8) * t;
```

should be

```
 _this.vx = (_this.vx *0.8) * t;//Assignment not addition
```

Also I'm assuming that `_this.ax *0.8` is a typo for `_this.vx *0.8`

Furthermore you should be checking for a minimum value of `_this.vx` to stop the update, because multiplying a fraction to a number is never going to make it zero. It should be checked for a minimum value which is same as zero for the purposes of the application.

Comment: However, it seems like doing this would conflict with the position of the boxes (_this.x) because position gets it values from the compounding of velocity.

Comment: That's alright, since you're trying to reduce it by a factor of `.8` per second it box should ultimately come is expected to come to rest.

Comment: Ultimately, for the X-value of the box it should appear as:                  
 `_this.vx = (_this.vx * 0.8) * t;
            _this.x += _this.vx * 0.8 * t;`